# How to replace last occurrence of characters in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm having a problem finding out how to replace the last ', ' in a string with ' and ':

Having this string:
test1, test2, test3

and I want to end out with:
test1, test2 and test3

I'm trying something like this:

```
var dialog = 'test1, test2, test3';    
dialog = dialog.replace(new RegExp(', /g').lastIndex, ' and ');
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
foo.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, ' and $1')
```

use the `$` (*end of line*) anchor to give you your position, and look for a pattern to the right of the comma index which does not include any further commas.

Edit:

The above works exactly for the requirements defined (though the replacement string is arbitrarily loose) but based on criticism from comments the below better reflects the spirit of the original requirement.

```js
console.log( 
   'test1, test2, test3'.replace(/,\s([^,]+)$/, ' and $1') 
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
result = dialog.replace(/,\s(\w+)$/, " and $1");
```

`$1` is referring to the first capturing group `(\w+)` of the match.

Comment: This will fail for strings like 'test-1, test-2, test-3', but again I'm confident the OP can make such adaptations themself.

Answer (score 0):

regex search pattern \s([^,]+)$

```
Line1: If not, sdsdsdsdsa sas ., sad, whaterver4
Line2: If not, fs  sadXD sad ,  ,sadXYZ!X
Line3: If not d,,sds,, sasa sd a, sds, 23233
```

Search with patterns finds 
    Line1: whaterver4
    Line3: 23233

Yet doesnt find  Line2: sadXYZ!X
Which is only missing a whitespace