# Replace last occurrence of character in string

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way in javascript to replace the last occurrence of an '_' (underscore) in a given string?

Comment: Is it always the last character of the string? If not, have a look at string.lastIndexOf(searchstring, start)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace last occurrence of characters in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

This will remove the last underscore:

```js
var str = 'a_b_c';
console.log(  str.replace(/_([^_]*)$/, '$1')  ) //a_bc
```

This will replace it with the contents of the variable `replacement`:

```js
var str = 'a_b_c',
    replacement = '!';

console.log(  str.replace(/_([^_]*)$/, replacement + '$1')  ) //a_b!c
```

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: what if the text to be replaced is not the underscore but the content of a variable called replaceMe?

How should the regex be modified?

Comment: @Pierpaolo: You'd have to create the regexp using a `new RegExp`, read all about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions - Remember to escape the `replaceMe` variable so it doesn't contain special characters that will alter the regular expression

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: thanks for the link. 

I already knew about the `new RegExp` syntax.

My question was more like "where should I put the variable replaceMe"?

e.g.: 
    `var aRegExpr = new RegExp("_([^"+replaceMe+"]*)$");`

Comment: @Pierpaolo: its not that simple tbh since you can have a word and not just a single char in a variable - you should start a new question about it :) It is too complicated for a comment here

Comment: Thanks. I understand, I will search whether there is already one.

Comment: Late but still for some one else who seeks help,
`str.replace(/(_)\w$/,'$1'+replacement)`

Comment: You forgot "", please add them

Comment: This does not work with following "david - Copy.txt" trying to replace "." instead of "_"

Comment: @David: that is probably because . (dot) is a special character in regular expressions that matches every other char. To use it literally you need to escape it

Answer (score 76):

No need for jQuery nor regex assuming the character you want to replace exists  in the string

**Replace last char in a string**

`str = str.substring(0,str.length-2)+otherchar`

**Replace last underscore in a string**

```
var pos = str.lastIndexOf('_');
str = str.substring(0,pos) + otherchar + str.substring(pos+1)
```

or use one of the regular expressions from the other answers

```js
var str1 = "Replace the full stop with a questionmark."
var str2 = "Replace last _ with another char other than the underscore _ near the end"

// Replace last char in a string

console.log(
  str1.substring(0,str1.length-2)+"?"
)  
// alternative syntax
console.log(
  str1.slice(0,-1)+"?"
)

// Replace last underscore in a string 

var pos = str2.lastIndexOf('_'), otherchar = "|";
console.log(
  str2.substring(0,pos) + otherchar + str2.substring(pos+1)
)
// alternative syntax

console.log(
  str2.slice(0,pos) + otherchar + str2.slice(pos+1)
)
```

Comment: `+1` for *no regex* & ***`lastIndexOf(...)` does the search from the END***  (better performance) so the currently accepted regexp even *can't* be faster.

Comment: "nor regex".... this solution doesn't work if string doesn't contain the underscore. Regex version does. You can't add the substitution character if not needed.

Comment: @tedebus please read the question. Also some of the examples can handle any last character

Comment: @mplungjan I read the question. In fact, my objection is related to the term "occurrence": there may be the element to be eliminated, but also not. The solution I read here adds a character regardless of whether it is necessary or not. I was not referring to the fact that the character could be different.

Comment: Updated to include that the char needs to exist

Answer (score 13):

What about this?

```
function replaceLast(x, y, z){
  var a = x.split("");
  a[x.lastIndexOf(y)] = z;
  return a.join("");
}

replaceLast("Hello world!", "l", "x"); // Hello worxd!
```

Answer (score 8):

Another super clear way of doing this could be as follows:

> ```
> let modifiedString = originalString
>    .split('').reverse().join('')
>    .replace('_', '')
>    .split('').reverse().join('')
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var someString = "(/n{})+++(/n{})---(/n{})$$$";
var toRemove = "(/n{})"; // should find & remove last occurrence 

function removeLast(s, r){
  s = s.split(r)
  return s.slice(0,-1).join(r) + s.pop()
}

console.log(
  removeLast(someString, toRemove)
)
```

### Breakdown:

```
s = s.split(toRemove)         // ["", "+++", "---", "$$$"]
```

```
s.slice(0,-1)                 //  ["", "+++", "---"]
```

```
s.slice(0,-1).join(toRemove)  // "})()+++})()---"
```

```
s.pop()                       //  "$$$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the string, replace the char, reverse the string.

Here is a post for reversing a string in javascript:  [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```js
    // Define variables
    let haystack = 'I do not want to replace this, but this'
    let needle = 'this'
    let replacement = 'hey it works :)'
    
    // Reverse it
    haystack = Array.from(haystack).reverse().join('')
    needle = Array.from(needle).reverse().join('')
    replacement = Array.from(replacement).reverse().join('')
    
    // Make the replacement
    haystack = haystack.replace(needle, replacement)
    
    // Reverse it back
    let results = Array.from(haystack).reverse().join('')
    console.log(results)
    // 'I do not want to replace this, but hey it works :)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to mplungjan's answer, but can be a bit easier (especially if you need to do other string manipulation right after and want to keep it as an array)
Anyway, I just thought I'd put it out there in case someone prefers it.

```js
var str = 'a_b_c';
str = str.split(''); //['a','_','b','_','c']
str.splice(str.lastIndexOf('_'),1,'-'); //['a','_','b','-','c']
str = str.join(''); //'a_b-c'
```

The '_' can be swapped out with the char you want to replace

And the '-' can be replaced with the char or string you want to replace it with