# Javascript - Reverse of the replace() method?

Tags: javascript, methods, replace

```
var str = "1, 2, 3";
var res = str.replace(","," and");
```

And the result of the variable 'res' is:

```
"1 and 2, 3"
```

But this is what I actually want:

```
"1, 2 and 3"
```

So how can I do so?

Comment: [Replace last occurence of character in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497318/replace-last-occurence-of-character-in-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no straight forward way to do this, you can get the last index of `,` in the string, exclude it, include the replacement and reconstruct the string.

```
var str = "1, 2, 3";
var lIndex  = str.lastIndexOf(",");
str = str.substring(0, lIndex) + " and" + str.substr(lIndex + 1);
console.log(str);
```

**Output**

```
1, 2 and 3
```

Comment: @chris97ong what do you expect??you are not paying here for answers..its a community build site not rent a coder

Answer (score 6):

Use regex as

```
str.replace(/\,(?=[^,]*$)/," and");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var str = "1, 2, 3";
    var new_str = str.replace(/\,(?=[^,]*$)/," and");
    alert(new_str); // alerts output-- 1, 2 and 3
```