# How to remove character from last array element

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the last element comma in Javascript array

```
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB,"];
```

I need the result below

```
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB"];
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your inputs

Comment: don't put it there in the first place? See this is the problem with such minimal code ...

Comment: Why do you want to leave the comma in the other element? Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/163918) to me.

Comment: or a KY problem

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to do this?

Comment: seriously, the answer to the question as shown is to not put the damn thing in there - sloppy questions get so many varied responses around here, they're mostly correct depending on the interpretation of the very vague question! I'd be getting to the bottom of why! perhaps he just needs `.join()`, rather than `.join('')` and then he doesn't need any `,` anywhere! voted unclear!

Comment: @ Jaromanda X - Please stop your nonsense comments

Comment: The only reason I can think of to have an array of strings with trailing commas *except* for the last element is if you don't know what the `.join()` method does. Once you get the desired result array, what do you plan to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB,"];

arr[arr.length - 1] = arr[arr.length - 1].replace(',', '');

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Note that this removes specifically the *first* comma in the last element, which works for the data shown where there is only one comma but might not be appropriate more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use with `replace()`

```js
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB,"];

arr[arr.length-1] = arr[arr.length-1].replace(/\,/g,"");

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This will remove all commas from string. Not necessarily last. Ex. `['ABC,', 'X,Y,Z,']`.

Comment: Using a regex is likely to be slower than a simple string in this case. @Tushar OP want to remove the comma from the *last* element. Not at the last index of the last element. So I think it complies.

Comment: Commas don't need to be escaped in regular expressions.

Comment: how about `.replace(/,$/,"");`

Comment: @QuentinRoy If string contains commas, not just last comma and OP want to keep it then this will not work.

Comment: @Tushar yes, but he never said the comma is always at the end nor that he wanted to keep comma not at the nor that there may be comma not at the end.

Comment: @Tushar in this case only single `,` is there .Op not mention only remove last `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[arr.length-1] = arr[arr.length-1].slice(0,-1)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: `.slice(0,-1)` is a lot more convenient than `.slice(0,arr[arr.length-1].length-1)`.

Comment: Considering OP is newbie, I'd add some explanation to the answer. It's always good to add explanation to answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the other way is this:

```js
var arr =  ["AAA,",",BBB,"];
arr.push(arr.pop().replace(/,$/, ''));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497365/5596800) answer explains how you can do it using regex:

```
>> var str = "BBB,"
>> str = str.replace(/,[^,]*$/ , "")
>> str
>> "BBB"
```

Comment: *"This answer explains"* - Well...it doesn't really *explain*, but it does show an example. Why have you put the `[^,]*` part in your regex? OP asked about removing a comma, not removing a comma and the characters that follow it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB,"];
var lastelmnt = arr[(arr.length)-1].replace(',', '');
arr.splice(((arr.length)-1),1,lastelmnt);
```

Output :

```
["AAA,", "BBB"]
```

Comment: that does exactly null

Comment: Even aside from the fact that this doesn't modify the array elements at all, why would you loop over the whole array when the question asks about modifying only the *last* element?

Comment: Now I need to changed my solution. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

using JavaScript string [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method & Array [**splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr =  ["AAA,","BBB,"];

var arrLastElement = arr[arr.length-1];

var splitStr =  arrLastElement.split(',');

var strWithoutComma = splitStr[0];

arr.splice(arr.length-1);
arr.push(strWithoutComma);

console.log(arr);
```