# Replace only the last occurrance in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace last occurrence of characters in a string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript)

This is my code :

```
var newValue= myString.replace(" ", "<br />");
```

but I'd like to replace only the last occurance, not ALL occurances.

Such as :

```
Hello my name is Marco
```

become

```
Hello my name is<br />Marco
```

How can I do it? I think regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with regex, I can only think of `replace(/ (?=[^ ]*$)/, "<br />")`. Not the best option, and does not work for more complicated regexes because it requires a "negation" of the whole expression.

Maybe it's easier with simple string manipulation:

```
var parts = myString.split(" ");
if (parts.length > 1)
    var last = parts.pop();
    return parts.join(" ") + "<br />" + last;
} else
    return myString;
```

You also could use [backward search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var index = myString.lastIndexOf(" ");
if (index > -1)
    return myString.substr(0, index) + "<br />" + myString.substr(index+1);
else
    return myString;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
.replace(/\s(?=\S*$)/, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.replace(/ ([^ ]*)$/, "<br />$1")
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vp5E4/)