# how to remove a comma and replace with a period javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, conditional-statements

I have a string that I have created where I would like to remove the last comma and replace it with a period. I want to keep all of the other commas. Here I was trying to use a conditional statement, it works to add commas, but it doesn't work to replace the last one with a period. I am new at this, I would really appreciate any help.

```
for (var i = 0; i < petArray.length; i++) {
    petObj = petArray[i];
    likesString = petObj.name + " " + " is a " + petObj.type + " she " + " likes ";
    for (var j = 0; j < petObj.likes.length; j++) {
        if (j < petObj.likes.length) {
            var likesString = likesString + petObj.likes[j] + ", ";
        }
        else if (j == petObj.likes.length) {
            likesString.replace(", ", ".");
        }
    }
    displayResult();
}
```

Comment: I answered, but then discovered this. Almost an exact duplicate of [How to Replace Last...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript) The answers are going to be identical.

Comment: @aerodynamo that article only deals with how to fix up the string after it is created, perhaps by a simple join() call. Part of the problem here is that the condition inside the loop is off-by-one and the condition of the else isn't needed and the result of the 'replace' isn't put back into the string and there is a spare 'var' and if you put the comma in on all the loop iterations, you should put the fixup after the loop ends, not on a condition for the 'last' loop iteration.

Comment: @LeeMeador Hmm... I get what you're saying, but the very top answer (and most of the answers that follow) show how to replace the last occurrence of a specific pattern with a different pattern. I mean, it's almost entirely identical except it checks for whitespace. If you take out \s and change ' and' to '.', the answer is entirely identical. I would agree that there are other issues with his code, but not directly related to the question he's asking. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the 'if' part of this has to always be true so the 'else' part is never executed:

```
for (var j = 0; j < petObj.likes.length; j++) {
    if (j < petObj.likes.length) {
        var likesString = likesString + petObj.likes[j] + ", ";
    }
    else if (j == petObj.likes.length) {
        likesString.replace(", ", ".");
    }
}
```

The for loop says to only continue if that condition is true and your code then tests the same condition.

You might just do something like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < petObj.likes.length; j++) {
    if (j < petObj.likes.length-1) {
        likesString = likesString + petObj.likes[j] + ", ";
    }
    else {
        likesString = likesString + petObj.likes[j] + ". ";
    }
}
```

There are better ways to do the condition that don't duplicate so much but that might do what you want. (Also I fixed the extra 'var' part.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it. As I said, I'm still learning this so usually my code is not as lean as it could be. Your reminder on how the if statement works was informative for me.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be doing it a hard way! Use the Arry's join() method to build the list.

```
for (var i = 0; i < petArray.length; i++) {
    petObj = petArray[i];
    likesString = petObj.name + " is a " + petObj.type + " she likes " +
                  petObj.likes.join(", ") + ".";
    displayResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
 str.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,".$1")
```

The regular expression matches on a comma followed by any number of non-commas all the way to the end of the string... by definition, this is the last comma. It works if there are no commas, one comma or any number of commas.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the last occurrence of a comma in a string with a period, you can use:

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf(",");
var newstr = str.substring(0, index) + "." + str.substring(index + 1);
```

After looking at your code, it seems epascarello's approach is the best. In addition to what he has pointed out, if there are no elements in the array, your string will somewhat abruptly end with: "she likes". To fix this, you could use:

```
likesString = petObj.name + " is a " + petObj.type + (petObj.likes.length ? ", she likes " + petObj.likes.join(", ") : "") + ".";
```

Comment: if there are no entries in the 'likes' array, there will be no comma.

Comment: @LeeMeador That would make no sense, since the string would end up being `"X is a y, she likes"`. Nevertheless, I've added code to cover this edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great place to learn and test regular expressions: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Essentially, you want to replace the following:

```
RegExp Pattern: /,([^,]+)$/
Replace Pattern: .$1
```

So your code should look like:

```
s.replace(/,([^,]+)$/, '.$1');
```

Where `s` is the string you're trying to replace the last comma in.

Don't forget to set that line to a variable to save it.

Answer (score 0):

For start you can avoid to put the last comma with a code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < petArray.length; i++) {
    petObj = petArray[i];
    var likesString = petObj.name + " " + " is a " + petObj.type;
    if (petObj.likes.length) {
       likesString = likesString + " she " + " likes " petObj.likes.join(", ");
    }
    likesString = likesString + '.'
    displayResult();
}
```

If you still want to use your code you have to test versus lenght-1 as the likes array indexes go from 0 to length-1:

```
for (var i = 0; i < petArray.length; i++) {
    petObj = petArray[i];
    var likesString = petObj.name + " " + " is a " + petObj.type + " she " + " likes ";
    for (var j = 0; j < petObj.likes.length; j++) {
      likesString = likesString + petObj.likes[j] + ((j == petObj.likes.length-1)?'.':', ';
    }
    displayResult();
}
```

If you still want to change the string after its construction you can just remove the last two characters

```
likesString=likesString.replace(/, $/,'.')
```

Comment: You said length-1 but didn't put it in the corrected code in the 'if' condition. The 'else' condition isn't needed at all.

Comment: @LeeMeador You are right, I skimmed the code (is that the term for fast reading) and assumed it was different of what was written in it. Fixed it (the first script also).

Answer (score -1):

That is because replace() returns a new string with the new value instead of changing the string itself, you could do this instead:

```
likesString = likesString.replace(/,\s$/, ".");
```

Comment: Hmm... This will replace only the first comma found from the string.

Comment: Yep, true. My bad. Fixed it now.

Comment: Now it's better, though if the comma isn't exactly the last character, it's not replaced. Anyway, OP's post is somehow inaccurate related to this. So downvote removed : ).

Comment: Nope, now it's replacing only a comma followed by some blank character : (. I'd rather use the previuos version : ).