# How to replace the last instance of a character in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the last instance of a comma with `and`. I have tried this:

```
myString = myString.replace('/_([^,]*)$/','and$1');
```

But the string is not affected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use a _ instead of a , ?

Comment: I believe the first issue is you have the regex wrapped in single quotes. You can just do `replace(/_([^,]*)$/,'and$1')`. The `/ ... /` marks the start and end of the regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace last occurrence of characters in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: I think regex is overkill here, simple string methods can be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a `_` instead of a `,` and you've wrapped your regex in quotes. I think you'll also need to add a space before the `and`:

`myString = myString.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,'\ and$1');`

---

Edit:

You could also do this without regex, if you're so inclined:

```
str = "Maria, David, Charles, Natalie";
lastComma = str.lastIndexOf(',');
newStr = str.substring(0, lastComma) + ' and' + str.substring(lastComma + 1);

//=> "Maria, David, Charles and Natalie"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `'` from regex or you need to use `RegExp()`. Also you can reduce regex with positive lookahead.

```js
var myString = 'abc,df,ef,shsg,dh';
myString = myString.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' and ');
// use `,` instead of `_`  --^-- here

document.write(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a `_` instead of a `,` in your regex. Use this one :

```
myString = myString.replace(/^(.*)(,)([^,]+)$/,'$1and$3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using _ instead of a ,

```
myString = myString.replace('/,([^,]*)$/','and$1');

DEMO:  https://regex101.com/r/dK9sM0/1
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace should like this one:

```
.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/,' and')
```