# R Remove specific character with range of possible positions within string

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to remove the character 'V' (always the last one in the strings) from the following vector containing a large number of strings. They look similar to the following example:

```
str <- c("VDM 000 V2.1.1",
         "ABVC 001 V10.15.0",
         "ASDV 123 V1.20.0")
```

I know that it is always the last 'V', I would like to remove.
I also know that this character is either the sixth, seventh or eighth last character within these strings.

I was not really able to come up with a nice solution. I know that I have to use sub or gsub but I can only remove all V's rather than only the last one.

Has anyone got an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `sub("V([^V]*)$", "\\1", str)`, adapted from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript).

Comment: @Richard: Would replace last "V" but not the last "V" restricted to the 6:8th location.

Answer (score 3):

This regex pattern is written to match a "V" that is then followed by 5 to 7 other non-"V" characters. The "[...]" construct is a "character-class" and within such constructs a leading "^" causes negation. The "{...} consturct allows two digits specifying minimum and maximum lengths, and the "$" matches the length-0 end-of-string which I think was desired when you wrote "sixth, seventh or eighth last character":

```
sub("(V)(.{5,7})$", "\\2", str)
[1] "VDM 000 2.1.1"    "ABVC 001 10.15.0" "ASDV 123 1.20.0"
```

Since you only wanted a single substitution I used `sub` instead of `gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
gsub("V(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)$","\\1",str)
##[1] "VDM 000 2.1.1"    "ABVC 001 10.15.0" "ASDV 123 1.20.0"
```

The regex `V(\\d+.\\d+.\\d+)$` matches the "version" consisting of the character "V" followed by three sets of digits (i.e., `\\d+`) separated by two "." at the end of the string (i.e., `$`). The parenthesis around the `\\d+.\\d+.\\d+` provides a group within the match that can be referenced by `\\1`. Therefore, `gsub` will replace the whole match with the group, thereby removing *that* "V".

Answer (score 1):

Since you know it's the last `V` you want to remove from the string, try this regex `V(?=[^V]*$)`:

```
gsub("V(?=[^V]*$)", "", str, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "VDM 000 2.1.1"    "ABVC 001 10.15.0" "ASDV 123 1.20.0"
```

The regex matches V before pattern `[^V]*$` which consists of non `V` characters from the end of the String, which guarantees that the matched `V` is the last `V` in the string.