# Node.Js Replacing The Last Found In A String

Tags: node.js, replace

I want to replace the last text it found in a string like this ;

`var string = "aaaaaaabbb"`

if i use `string = string.replace(/a/, "text")` it would replace the first one it found, but i want to make it replace the **LAST** one it finds!

Comment: So ask yourself: what does "last" mean, and then write that out as a match pattern. Just `a` is obviously not enough, how would you, given your own data, describe what "the last `a`" means to someone who has no idea what "last" means? Because that's what we're working with at the moment: a very dumb computer that can only do what you tell it to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace last occurrence of characters in a string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829483/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down the problem in two steps:

1. Find the last ocurrence of your search string
2. Replace the found ocurrence

A straightforward implementation might look like this

```
function replaceLast(input, search, replacement) {
   // Find last ocurrence
   const index = input.lastIndexOf(search);
   if (index === -1) {
     return input;
   }
   // Replace ocurrence
   return input.substring(0, index) + replacement + input.substring(index + search.length);
}
```